# vim omnicomplete vs. vim intellisense

Tags: c++, intellisense, vim, omnicomplete

Are [Vim OmniComplete](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/version7.html#new-omni-completion) and [Vim Intellisense](http://insenvim.sourceforge.net/) mutually exclusive or complementary?  I'm a bit confused by conflicting terminology and implementations, such as these [C++ OmniComplete](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/C%2B%2B_code_completion) and  [C++ Intellisence](http://insenvim.sourceforge.net/plugin/cpp/cppft.html) plugins.

Comment: There's also Clang-based completion plugin that probably does better than either of those two (but I haven't tried it).

Comment: @Tronic:  Could you provide a link?

Comment: I don't think the plugin was ever really published. Ask on the #llvm IRC channel as the author of the plugin is there.

Comment: I just installed a Clang-based one called clang_complete http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3302. Haven't really put it through its paces yet but looks really nice so far. It doesn't even need a ctags file.

Comment: @Gene Goykhman:  Does it do completion on standard libraries and Boost as well?

Comment: @Robert S. Barnes: not that I can tell, and there seem to be some other limitations (constructors don't seem to complete, for example). I need to play with it some more to see if these are just configuration things though.

Comment: Consider also [coc](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) which aims to be an intellisense engine for vim

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Vim Omnicomplete is a feature of Vim version 7, on all platforms.
Vim  Intellisense is a plugin for vim 6.1 and 6.2 on Windows only.

Comment: Yeah, just took a look at the Intellisense FAQ http://insenvim.sourceforge.net/vis_faq.htm - 4. Does it run on Linux?

NO. It does not work on Linux. But we want to port to Linux, but we don't have much experience working on Linux. Any help in porting to Linux will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

OmniComplete and Intellisense are different words for the same thing,
a kind of autocompletion system.

Intellisence is a trademark of Microsoft. So the author of vim (Bram Moolenaar)
decided to give this feature a new name, OmniComplete.

If you want to have autocompletion for C++ you have either to activate/configure
the build-in OmniCompletion or you have to install the plug-in Vim C++ Intellisense.

Comment: Could you by any chance provide a link to the announcement for this? Not a big deal, I'm just curious.

Comment: This answer isn't quite what the OP wanted:  Vim Intellisense is a seperate plugin he linked that is distinct from Omnicomplete.  However, you're right about the choice of names. You can find more about the name in the vim documentation.

Comment: @icco: see :help new-omni-completion

Comment: Not sure that `OmniComplete and Intellisense are different words for the same thing`. Intellisense is contextual. I mean if you have an instance, it shows you only his properties and methods. OmniCompletion shows you every matches.